How to do sorting by ASC with excluding null in GraphQl?
I am using Hot Chocolate for my GraphQL and using its sorting functionality.
Here, when I use sort by date with DESC or ASC then it is giving me the desired result (this date can be null). Let's say when I am getting 10 records where 2 are null, then I want to get first 8 records by ASC of date and then keep null at the last.
How to do that? Below is the current behavior which I want to tweak.
Query:
query {
  getRecords(
    skip: 0
    take: 10
    where: {
      and: [
        { location: { contains: "MyLocation" } }
      ]
    }
    order: { earliestPaymentDateTime: DESC }
  ) {
    items {
      earliestPaymentDateTime
    }
  }
}

Output:
{
  "data": {
    "getRecords": {
      "items": [
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-03-25T16:00:51.830Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-03-20T12:02:42.000-04:00"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-03-18T20:48:12.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-02-08T23:05:28.598Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-02-01T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-01-30T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-01-25T17:12:49.221Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2023-12-08T22:22:46.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Desired Output:
{
  "data": {
    "getRecords": {
    "items": [
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2023-12-08T22:22:46.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-01-25T17:12:49.221Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-01-30T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-02-01T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-02-08T23:05:28.598Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-03-18T20:48:12.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-03-20T12:02:42.000-04:00"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-03-25T16:00:51.830Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

If custom sorting, is the answer then I'm doing something wrong:
I can see the null between desc dates. How to push null at the bottom?
Ideally, I want this behavior
.OrderByDescending(x => x.EarliestPaymentDateTime.HasValue)
.ThenBy(x => x.EarliestPaymentDateTime)
.ThenBy(x => SOME_OTHER_FIELD)

Custom Sorting Logic:
public class ExceptionSortType: SortInputType<ExceptionResponseDto>
{
    protected override void Configure(ISortInputTypeDescriptor<ExceptionResponseDto> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.BindFieldsExplicitly();
        descriptor.Field(x => x.EarliestPaymentDateTime).Type<AscOnlySortEnumType>();
    }
}

public class AscOnlySortEnumType : DefaultSortEnumType
{
    protected override void Configure(ISortEnumTypeDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Operation(DefaultSortOperations.Descending);
    }
}

Result:
"items": [
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2023-12-08T22:22:46.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-01-25T17:12:49.221Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-01-30T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-02-01T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": null
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-02-08T23:05:28.598Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-03-18T20:48:12.000Z"
        },
        {
          "earliestPaymentDateTime": "2024-03-20T12:02:42.000-04:00"
        }
      ]


You're going to need to customize sorting behavior on your server to put nulls last.

I have updated my question with Custom Sorting logic. Here, I am trying to push null at the end of the sort. What am I missing here?
